# Свернуть group в NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Как свернуть несколько item, объединенных в group  в одну строчку, и по нажатию на неё раскрывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно, разобрался и сделал код.

activity_main_drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting_string"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_memory_24"
        android:title="Настройки программы" />

    <group android:id="@+id/setting_menu"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="Настройки программы"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_memory_24" >
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_sett_1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_memory_24"
                    android:title="..." />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/check_error"
        android:icon="@drawable/engine_2"
        android:title="@string/menu2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/hidden"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_miscellaneous_services_24"
        android:title="@string/menu3" />
</group>
```

Функцию вывода NavigationDrawer посадил на кнопку, по её нажатию вызов функции создания NavigationDrawer (1 часть):

```
public void _make_navi() {
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);

    TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView_nav2);
    TextView tvmain = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.text_nav);
    ImageView back = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.setting_menu, setting_show); // это основная строчка показа группы скрытой

    tvmain.setText("..... v." + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

    navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Далее в функции обработки нажатий

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (id == R.id.setting_string) {
        setting_show = !setting_show; // переключаем
        _make_navi();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ну и в самом начала класса объявляем переменную

```
boolean setting_show = false;
```

Копировал со своего кода, так что не обессудьте. Может ещё кривовато, но пусть каждый сам подстроит под себя